# Create a zip file using PHP class ZipArchive without writing the file to disk?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I would like to create a zip file in memory using a ZipArchive (or a native PHP class) and read the content of the file back to the client.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

The files that I want to zip in this application are a maximum of 15 MB total.  I think we should be in good shape memory-wise.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061710/php-zip-files-on-the-fly

Comment: and how will you handle zip archives that exceed the amount of memory available to PHP?

Comment: please let this question stay open, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061710/php-zip-files-on-the-fly was asked in a way that it could receive useful answers.

Comment: sorry, your comment has confused me. Please explain.

Comment: @Oddthinking, sorry about that.  The other question and answers skip over the part where the zip file is opened for writing (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-open.php), which is the crux of the entire problem.  If that is not addressed, the problem can not be solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulate an Archive in memory with PHP (without creating a temporary file on disk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189019/manipulate-an-archive-in-memory-with-php-without-creating-a-temporary-file-on-d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following library, it allows creating zip files and returning them as a stream: [PHPClasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6110-PHP-Create-archives-of-compressed-files-in-ZIP-format.html).

Comment: I would like something that is native to the standard php library.

Comment: If I may ask, is there a reason for that?

Comment: So I do not have to drag in a dependency and maintain it over time.  If it is included in the standard library, I will not have to worry about incompatibly when I upgrade php versions.

Comment: Actually, it's a PHP class. And it requires PHP5. Upgrade concerns should be worrying you when PHP6 arrives (not anytime soon).

Comment: @Chris: You may have a look too at http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/ (suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990462/generating-zip-files-with-php-apache-on-the-fly-in-high-speed)

Comment: @FrostyZ This should have been an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try [**ZipStream**](https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP) (link to GitHub repo, also supports install via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)).

From original author's website (now dead):

> ZipStream is a library for dynamically streaming dynamic zip files
>   from PHP without writing to the disk at all on the server.

Comment: I found this to be a good replacement for the dead link: https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP

`$zip = new \ZipStream\ZipStream('bulk-export.zip');
$zip->addFile('users.csv', '(csv data generated by another method here)');
$zip->finish();`

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Frosty Z for the great library ZipStream-PHP. We have a use case to **upload** some large zip files in quantity and size to S3. The official documentation does not mention how to upload to S3.

So we've had an idea to stream the zip created by ZipStream output directly to S3 without creating the zip file on the server.

Here is a working sample code that we came up with:

```
<?php
# Autoload the dependencies
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use ZipStream\Option\Archive as ArchiveOptions;

//s3client service
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => '<AWS_KEY>',
        'secret' => '<AWS_SECRET_KEY>',
    ]
]);
$s3Client->registerStreamWrapper(); //required

$opt = new ArchiveOptions();
$opt->setContentType('application/octet-stream');
$opt->setEnableZip64(false); //optional - for MacOs to open archives

$bucket = 'your_bucket_path';
$zipName = 'target.zip';

$zip = new ZipStream\ZipStream($zipName, $opt);

$path = "s3://{$bucket}/{$zipName}";
$s3Stream = fopen($path, 'w');

$zip->opt->setOutputStream($s3Stream); // set ZipStream's output stream to the open S3 stream

$filePath1 = './local_files/document1.zip';
$filePath2 = './local_files/document2.zip';
$filePath3 = './local_files/document3.zip';

$zip->addFileFromPath(basename($filePath1), $filePath1);
$zip->addFileFromPath(basename($filePath2), $filePath2);
$zip->addFileFromPath(basename($filePath3), $filePath3);

$zip->finish(); // sends the stream to S3
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread talking about this:
[Manipulate an Archive in memory with PHP (without creating a temporary file on disk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189019/manipulate-an-archive-in-memory-with-php-without-creating-a-temporary-file-on-d/37581294#37581294)

nettle has suggested to use zip.lib.php from [phpmyadmin](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin). I think this is a rather solid solution.

FYI **zip.lib.php** does not exist anymore, it has been replace by **ZipFile.php** in the same libraries/ folder.