# Downloading a csv as a zip

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, csv, zip

Im using Php (Zend Framework) to download a datagrid as CSV..the csv generation works fine.I just want to know is it possible to download the csv file within a zip file

My current code

```
public function downloadCsvAction(){
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=answers_csv.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        echo "stuff1" . ",";
        echo "stuff2".",";
        //----bla bla

   exit;

}
```

By calling the url `controller/downloadCsv` im getting a popup to save the csv.I want the csv to be in a zip file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple code to zip and output csv as a zip file

```
//here is your csv file
$csvFile    = "test.csv";

//location for php to create zip file.
$zipPath    = "/tmp/$csvFile.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($zipPath,ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
    $zip->addFile($csvFile, $csvFile);
    $zip->close();
    //Make sure the zip file created and output it.
    if(is_file($zipPath)){
        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$csvFile.'.zip"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipPath));
        readfile($zipPath,false);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know is it possible to download the csv file within a zip file

Yes it is possible. Just create a ZIP-file and put the CSV-file in there. Then deliver the ZIP-file.

If you're looking for more *technical* info, please read into the related Q&A material as the concrete code differs highly on what you need to achieve:

- [Generating ZIP files with PHP + Apache on-the-fly in high speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/990462/367456)

Comment: a little more info..or  link would be perfect :)

Comment: @ubercooluk: I suspect the CSV is very large so I assume you want to create the ZIP-file on the fly as well, so please see the edit.

Comment: Yes the csv is very large(may contains up to 10,000 lines or sometimes 100 lines) ..Thanks for the links ill look into it

Comment: is it a good idea to use this way of downloading..for a large file ?

Comment: well, I suppose you want to *stream* it, so anything that works with streaming is a good idea I'd say. You can also temporary create the zipfile on disk and deliver it. However as you only deliver a single file, HTTP compression might be more useful. It depends a bit on what is actually needed and also a bit on the server configuration to really say what a good idea is.